# Assign first element in multidimensional array to one dimensional array

Tags: java

I am trying to add the first element of each array in the two-dimensional array *folderArray* into a one dimensional array called *tempArray* as can be seen in the code shown below. However I am getting a null pointer exception from the tempArray. How can I fix this?

```
    int listLength = folderArray.length;
    String tempArray[] = null;
    for(int x = 0; x<listLength;x++){
        tempArray[x] = folderArray[x][0];
    }
```

Comment: What do you think `String tempArray[] = null;` does?

Comment: @ZouZou I cant use the tempArray inside the for loop without initializing it to null or else i get an error

Comment: But what do you think initializing it to `null` does? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialise your `tempArray` before you can assign anything to its elements:

```
String tempArray[] = new String[listLength];
```

is a good start (instead of `String tempArray[] = null;`)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are assigning  `tempArray[]` as  `null`

Change it as,
 
 `String tempArray[] = new String[listLength];`